# Alloy symmetry breaking does not work

Tags: alloy

i am using the Alloy api to generate some models.

Recently I realized that Alloy generates an isomorph models.
Is symmetry breaking default?

kind regards,

Comment: We might need more details to understand what went supposedly wrong

Answer (score 1):

Yes, symmetry breaking is on by default.  (Actually, I'm not aware of any way to turn it off, so "default" may not be quite the right word to use for it.)

If you find multiple isomorphic models among your results, it is because the Alloy Analyzer makes a performance / symmetry-breaking tradeoff.  The tradeoff is discussed following section 5.2.1 of *Software abstractions*:

> [The Analyzer] generates symmetry-breaking constraints from the model, and conjoins them to the analysis constraint.  If they were perfect, these constraints would rule out all but one assignment in each equivalence class, but that turns out to require very large symmetry-breaking constraints, which would overload the solver and actually damage performance.  The analyzer therefore generates a much smaller constraint, which breaks only some of the symmetries, but in practice eliminates a very high proportion (over 99%) of the assignments.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful. I also found that in the book.